# Execute two node commands from a bash file as Docker CMD

Tags: node.js, bash, dockerfile

I am trying to run a nodejs app from a file named `start.sh`.

I am using this file because I want to execute two process in a serial way as a CMD in a Dockerfile.

This is the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
node /get-secrets.mjs -c /secrets-config.json -t /.env.production
npm run start -p 8000
```

As you can notice, I want to perform two things:

- First execute the get-secrets.mjs file, that is a small script that internally uses `commander.js` two read the flags `-c` and `-t` (--config and --target respectively). These flags receive strings arguments to locate files.
- The second command is just the start for my node js app.

I have no idea how should I write this file, because those commands work on my machine but in the container it seems my format is wrong.

This is the problem so far:

[image: Error message]

How should I pass the arguments to the mjs script?

Comment: It looks like it's interpreting your `start.sh` script as a piece of node (Javascript) code. Perhaps you need to take a step back and look at how you create/configure your container.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Erwin. Could you please help me with some ideas?

Comment: @Herber230 edit your post to include the Dockerfile.

Comment: @programmerq I think I have to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD. Also, I had some little issue copying my sh file from windows to the image. I just posted my solution. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else fine this useful, I solved my issue using this:

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine

# Dependencies that my script needs
RUN npm i -g @aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager@3.121.0 commander@9.3.0

# Folder for my source code
WORKDIR /app

# SOME OTHER COMMANDS
# ...

# In this folder I have the start.sh and the get-secrets.mjs files
COPY ${SOURCE_PATH}/server-helpers/* ./

# This was required since I am working on windows
RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start.sh" ]
```